# How to customize Modern forms? Field Customizer replaced CSR for views but what about forms?

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-side-rendering, modern, fieldcustomizers

In classic we had CSR (JSlink) for views and most of the forms.

Field Customizers could replace CSR for list views, as described here:

[Migrating from JSLink to SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-jslink-to-spfx-extensions)

But what about modern forms? How to customize them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the below options:

1. You can use **PowerApps** to customize the SharePoint online List forms.

   Check below article for more information:

   [Customize a SharePoint list form by using PowerApps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form).
2. You can also use **InfoPath(Microsoft will support InfoPath upto 2026)** to customize the list forms.
3. You can also build the fully customized forms using **[SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)** and add them to Modern pages.
4. **Third Party tools**: Nintex, K2, StratusForms, etc.

Comment: Thank You @Ganesh!